# Cada cuanto hay que hacer una migracion en RAILS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

En las guías y tutoriales dice que cuando se crea un modelo, se crea una migración que luego ejecutas con `rake db:migrate`.

¿Pero en qué otros casos hay que crear una migración y ejecutarla?

¿Cuándo cambias el modelo, hay que crearla? ¿Hay que crearla manualmente o se puede generar de forma automática?

Answer (score 1):

Las migraciones son una forma conveniente de modificar su base de datos de una manera estructurada y organizada.

Si necesitas generarlas cuando quieres agregar columnas a una tabla o modificar tu modelo.
Se puede crear manualmente y también de forma automática con

```
rails g migration addColumnToUsers
```

por ejemplo.

Si quieres saber más de migraciones puedes leer estas guías:
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html
- http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Las migraciones son los cambios que hagas a tablas en la base de datos. No deberias Hacer cambios directamente en la base de datos, lo ideal y correcto es hacer cambios a traves de migraciones.

En cuanto a cuando ejecutar un db:migrate, es al terminar tu migracion.

Tambien se da el caso de que el mismo rails te da un mensaje informandote de que hay una migracion pendiente por desplegar.

Saludos.